# How to run a select query multiple times from first select query set of results?

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot seem to figure out how to take the results from a query and use them in another query.  To keep it simple I will just say I have a table called saved_players and is set up like so..

```
Username     playername
user1         player1
user1         player2
user2         player1
user1         player3
user3         player1
```

Here is the query I am using to echo all this information only for the user that is logged in.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM saved_players WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['login']."'";

$result = $conn->query($query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "
    <table class='tablebox' width='300' border='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr>


    <td width='200' style='color: #4f4e4e; font-size: 19px;'>". $row["[playername"]."</td>

    </tr>

    </table>";


    }
} 

?>
```

If user "user1" is logged in this of course will display

```
player1
player2
player3
```

How do I run a new query with each of these names?  The ultimate goal of all this is to take each player name from the results (in this case player1, player 2, and player 3) and run a query similar to this

```
$query= "SELECT COUNT(playername) AS Totalnumber FROM saved_players WHERE playername = '' ";
```

I am trying to count how many times each of these players have been added to table saved_players by all users and divide that number by the amount of members I have.  But I need this done for only the players that the logged in user has added to saved_players.  Sure hope this makes any sense at   Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can use join inside your first query to get count of all player names

Comment: @MahaDev can you show me an example of how I would use join to get a count of the specific players I got from first query?  While reading about join is speaks about 2 different tables.  Do I need two tables to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

use this query :-

```
$query = "SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(playername) FROM saved_players as tab1 
WHERE tab1.playername = tab1.playername) 
AS Totalnumber FROM saved_players as tab2 
WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['login']."'"
```

Mysql query like that:-

```
SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(playername) FROM saved_players as tab1 
    WHERE tab1.playername = tab1.playername) 
    AS Totalnumber FROM saved_players as tab2 
    WHERE username = 'user1'
```

Comment: That's not how you use `HAVING`. You use `HAVING` with a aggregate function.

Comment: this is getting me closer.  But it seems to only be counting how many rows are in saved_players table all together.  I need something that first finds which playernames the logged in user has added to saved_players.  Then count how many times each of those names has been added to saved_players by all users.  Then divide that number by total members.

Comment: use **$_SESSION['login']** for find  logged in user  @user3765759

Comment: even when using $_SESSION['login'] it still is only counting the total rows in saved_players table.  Can you tell me what the tab1 and tab2 is doing in your example?

Comment: tab1 or tab2 are alias name  of tables

Answer (score 0):

Try this code logic:

```
         <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM saved_players WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['login']."'";

            $result = $conn->query($query);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // output data of each row

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                echo "
                <table class='tablebox' width='300' border='0' cellspacing='0'>
                <tr>


                <td width='200' style='color: #4f4e4e; font-size: 19px;'>". $row["[playername"]."</td>";
            /*
            Your logic can be placed here...

 $query= "SELECT COUNT(playername) AS Totalnumber FROM saved_players WHERE playername = '' GROUP BY playername HAVING Totalnumber > 0";

    The above is only an example...
    but if you still wish to get 0 number of players then disregard the HAVING Part
    --------------------------------------------------------------------

       // In your inner SQL query you may use group by with HAVING
            get the value you expect in this query

            */



                echo"</tr>

                </table>";


                }
            } 

            ?>
```

hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I have never used group by with HAVING so I wouldn't even know where to start with it.  Can you show me a quick example?